# Cannot get it to accept input

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

when input is asked, I type Rock it loops back as though i did not type the right input.
I've tried retyping the error checking but nothing is working. The only input it will accept is 'q'. Here is the code:

```
import random

user_wins = 0 #setting default score
computer_wins = 0

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True:
    user_input = input('Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ').lower()
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    if user_input not in options:
        continue

random_number = random.randint(0, 2) #rock: 0 , paper: 1, scissors: 2

computer_pick = options[random_number] #using computer's pick from a random from the list to be stored.

print('Computer picked:', computer_pick + ".") #printing the result of computer's pick

if user_input == "rock" and computer_pick == "scissors": #setting win or lose conditions
    print('Rock Crushes Scissors...You Win!')
    user_wins += 1

elif user_input == "paper" and computer_pick == "rock":
    print('Paper Covers Rock...You Win!')
    user_wins += 1

elif user_input == "scissors" and computer_pick == "paper":
    print('Scissors Cuts Paper...You Win!')
    user_wins += 1

else:
    print("You Lose")
    computer_wins += 1

print("You won ", user_wins, "times.")
print("Computer won ", computer_wins, "times.")
print('Goodbye')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you need to break the loop when input is in options, so the loop could be

```
while True:
    user_input = input('Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ').lower()
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    if user_input not in options:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Anyways, a better implementation could be creating the empty option and assign it if matches, so

```
answer = ''
while not answer:
    user_input = input('Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ').lower()
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    elif user_input in options:
        answer = user_input
```

Comment: Hi, ty for the answer. I am running into the game not continuing to go till the user quits. That answer did solve the input issue. But now the game ends on each attempt rather than continuing and making a running score.

Answer (score 0):

In you case try this code. You will need to have two while loops: one is for checking the input, the other is for continuing the game.

```
exit = False #this helps you to exit from the main while loop.
while not exit: 
     options = ['rock', 'scissors', 'paper']
     user_input = ""
     while True: 
         user_input = input('pls write paper, rock, scissors, or 
         q(quit) ').lower() 
         if user_input in options: 
             break 
         elif user_input == 'q': 
             exit = True 
             break 
     #do some calculations
# do some summary calculations and print them
```

I hope you will find it helpful)

Comment: Hello, ty for answer. The problem now becomes it will end the game on each attempt. Was going for it continuing game till user quits and there being a running score of win/loss. It did solve the input problem though ty.